# Hive query with more counts

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to execute a certain query and I could need some help.
On the one hand it want to sum the counts of the first 100 users but then I want to divide it through the amount of all rows of table1. But how can I do that? I cant use another count in the Select statement because of the group by.

```
From(
SELECT count(1) AS count FROM table1
GROUP BY Username
ORDER BY count DESC limit 100
) r
Select sum(r.count)/?(Amount of all rows of table1)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the intended result for your query would be. Could you add some sample data and expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

write two queries one counting with the limit and the other without. join them with no "on" clause and the do the dividing.

Comment: Hi, I allready did this with:                                 Select count(*),sum(b.count) as count from table1 f join 
(
SELECT  username,
count(*) AS count FROM table1
group by username
order by count desc limit 100000
) b                                                                 But its not working

Comment: should be something like this : 
select sum(counter_per_user) as sum_of_100_counts,
total_counter from 
(select count(\*) total_counter from table1) a join 
(select username,count(\*) counter_per_user from table1 group by username limit 100) b
group by total_counter

In b you have counts for first 100 users. In a you have the total counter. After the join for each user you have its own count and the total counter and then you sum the first 100 counters and have the total count